# Getting error while using @aws-sdk/client-sqs in node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-nodejs

While using the `sendMessage` method of SQS getting the following error
`error SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0 Deserialization error: to see the raw response, inspect the hidden field {error}.$response on this object. at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at /var/www/html/apachedev/git/repo/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sqs/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:1981:21`

Error is coming from the following part of Aws_json1_0.js
Here the `encoded` variable is having this value `There was an internal server error.`

```
const parseBody = (streamBody, context) => collectBodyString(streamBody, context).then((encoded) => {
    if (encoded.length) {
        console.log(encoded);
        return JSON.parse(encoded);
    }
    return {};
});
```

Code snippet:

```
import { SQS } from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";
async enqueueMessage(message: NewMessage): Promise<QueuedMessage> {    
    console.log(message, MESSAGE_QUEUE_URL);
    const result = await this.sqsClient
      .sendMessage({
        QueueUrl: MESSAGE_QUEUE_URL,
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(message),
      });
    console.log("RESULT", result);
    return {
      id: result.MessageId || '',
      ...message,
    };
  }
```

In the above snippet the message and the queue url looks correct.

value of message:

```
{
  user_id: '68057407',
  queued_by: 'abc@gmail.com',
  action: 'download',
  filters: {},
  report_id: 10,
  title: 'Title',
  download_id: 3722
}
```

value of MESSAGE_QUEUE_URL: http://localhost:9324/queue/jobQueue

versions:
"@aws-sdk/client-sqs": "^3.431.0"
Node.js: v18.18.1

Tried to use the sendMessage method, but it didn't add the message to the queue.

Comment: `'There was an internal server error.'` is not valid JSON, whereas `'"There was an internal server error."'` is. Does that help you?

Comment: I think it should have the value of the message that is passed as MessageBody in the sendMessage method in the code snippet. Where is it going wrong not able to understand.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what exactly is received and send by each function, and which line exactly causes the error. But from the error it's clear that at some point there is an attempt to `JSON.parse` a string that was either already parsed from JSON, or wasn't `JSON.stringify` first. By logging the variables you should see it, as in my first comment a JSON encoded string must have double quotes **inside** the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Localstack? I saw the `MESSAGE_QUEUE_URL` to be pointing to `http://localhost:9324`. If yes, you may need to pull the latest image from yesterday (11/23/23)

There was a recent change in the AWS SDK wherein the AWS JSON protocol is used by default. However, Localstack expects the AWS query protocol format.

https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/8267#issuecomment-1803663216

Comment: I haven't tried to resolve it yet, as everything worked fine after moving to the staging.  I was using "softwaremill/elasticmq-native" this docker image. Most probably this is the correct answer.

Comment: Verified, this is working after taking the latest pull.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem downgrading AWS SDK to 3.398.0

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, downgrading AWS SDK also helped me. I think the problem is with the newest SDK version.